# Get a selection of digits only if preceded by a minimum of x digits

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a number: 6278041121932517

If I want to get 11219325

I have a regex of:

```
re.search(r"((1|2)\d{7})", "6278041121932517")
```

but the thing is, it might begin with a 1 or a 2. So I want to add a minimum buffer beforehand say, 4 digits. I thought about look-behind, but it doesn't support n lengths.

Comment: *4 characters* - implies any characters or only digits in your case?

Comment: You do not need a positive lookbehind when no overlapping matches are expected, capturing is almost always enough.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah it will be digits only in this case

Comment: What do mean with "it does not support n length"? It does not support variable length but as I understand you want fixed length of at least 4 digits preceding `[12]` so how about [`(?<=\d{4})[12]\d{7}`](https://regex101.com/r/7ybQYq/1) (performance is better without lookbehind)

Comment: @bobblebubble yes what I meant was variable length, i.e. undetermined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
^\d{4,}?([12]\d{7})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u9xlfG/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{4,}?` - 4 or more digits, but as few as possible
- `([12]\d{7})` - Group 1 (your value):

  - `[12]` - `1` or `2`
  - `\d{7}`  - 7 digits

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/pKo4wq):

```
import re
m = re.search(r"^\d{4,}?([12]\d{7})", "6278041121932517")
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
# => 11219325
```

Comment: many thanks, having done regex in a little while so I've forgotten quite a bit, will mark when can. I also tried that `\d{4,}` before but I didn't have the question mark, so that's where it failed also.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is a "buffer," you don't even need to change the regex for that. Just slice off a few characters.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"((1|2)\d{7})", "6278041121932517").group()
'27804112'
>>> re.search(r"((1|2)\d{7})", "6278041121932517"[4:]).group()
'11219325'
```

Comment: that's true, didn't think of that :\